# add local css file in webview

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I want to display the content of a html string in a `Webview` and use a css file to resize the images and change the font-family.

I put a css file named `style.css` in the `assets/CSS/` folder.
And I tried to add this file to my html string  `data[3]`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                "<link href=\"style.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/>" +
                "</head>" +
                "<body>");
        sb.append(data[3]);
        sb.append("</body>" +
                "</html>");

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://android_asset/",sb.toString(),"text/html","UTF-8","");
```

In my css file, I have this :

```
 img {
width : 100%;
height : auto;
}

div {
font-family : "Times New Roman";
}
```

But I don't understand why the css file doesn't do his job.

When I display my html code, it seems good : `<html><head><link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/></head><body><p style="text-align: justify;">Je souhaite aujourd’hui vous faire un retour sur mon dernier Trail en date avec mes petites nouvelles, les Spyridon MR de VFF.</p>`

Am I missing something ?

Please help me, I tried everything.

Comment: Does the CSS file exist at that location, but just seem to not affect the html elements or does the file throw a 404 error?

Comment: There is no error and the file exist in app/src/main/assets/CSS

Comment: Well in your example, you're applying the font change to a div, but there are no divs in your html example. There is also no image. Is the style.css in the correct location relative to your html file?

Comment: 'app/src/main/assets/CSS'. You are not mentioning subfolder CSS in your html or in baseurl parameter. Try without that folder first.

Comment: ' sb.append(data[3]);'. ?????? Please explain what that statement should do.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't want to put all my string html :

```
    <html><head><link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/></head><body><p style="text-align: justify;">Je souhaite aujourd’hui vous faire un retour sur mon dernier Trail en date avec mes petites nouvelles, les Spyridon MR de VFF.</p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Pour la reprise de la saison, j’ai choisi de m’aligner encore une fois au départ du mythique « Trail ardéchois ». Cette année je me suis lancé sur le format 36km pour mieux préparer mes prochains Trails longs et Ultra prévus cette année.</p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">J’ai récemment fait l’achat de mes VFF Spyridon MR :</p>
    <p><a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'outbound-article', , '']);" ><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1322" src="" alt="vff" width="479" height="285" /></a></p>
    <p class="p2" style="text-align: justify;"><span class="s1">J’ai choisi ces chaussures par souci de légèreté et volonté de passer à des chaussures 5 doigts.</span></p>
    <p class="p2" style="text-align: justify;"><span class="s1">J’ai effectué quelques entraînements avec, avant de me lancer sur le 36km.</span></p>
   <p class="p2" style="text-align: justify;"><span class="s1"> Pour ne pas changer mes habitudes, j’ai pris le départ avec mon fidèle destrier Aloïs Bataille avec qui je cours la grande partie de mes Trails et avec qui je m’entraine.</span></p>
    <p class="p2"><a href=""><img class="aligncenter size-large wp-image-1323" src="" alt="FullSizeRender" width="640" height="480" /></a></p>
   <p class="p2"><a href=""><img class="aligncenter size-large wp-image-1324" src="" alt="FullSizeRender[1]" width="640" height="853" /></a></p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Nous avons bouclé ce magnifique parcours dans les hauts plateaux du vivarais en 4h24 minutes et finissons 86ème et 87ème sur un peu moins de 500 finishers.</p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Les Spyridon MR se sont révélées très agréables de par leur légèreté et par leur semelle suffisamment robuste pour ne pas me faire souffrir des pieds ( cailloux, branches, etc … ). Ce fût également une surprise de voir le nombre de traileurs attirés par ce type de course et de voir l’intérêt porté vers le minimalisme. Enfin, j’ai terminé ce trail par une interview très rapide sur ma course en VFF par l’animateur de la course pour donner un retour aux différents coureurs.</p>
   <p style="text-align: justify;"><a href=""><img class="aligncenter wp-image-1325 size-large" alt="IMG_2078" width="640" height="853" /></a></p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Je vous laisse donc avec ces dernières photos et vous souhaite à tous de prendre du plaisir en minimaliste. N’hésitez pas à commenter ou posez vos questions, je me ferais une joie de vous répondre.</p>
    <p>Julien</p>
   <p><a href="http://leminimaliste.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/IMG_2070.jpg"><img class="aligncenter size-large wp-image-1326" alt="IMG_2070" width="640" height="853" /></a></p>
    </body></html>
```

I remove some links in  and  but my html string is good and the images are here.

In data[3] there is just my html string.

And I'm not mentioning subfolder CSS because I found in another post that we have to do like that.